# twig url condition multiple domain

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a multiple domain

I want in my twig file give a condition to my current domain.

I try :

```
 {% set path = app.request.getSchemeAndHttpHost() %}
 {% if(path == 'http://mysite.it/')%}
     <img src="{{asset('images/xxxx.jpg')}}" alt="profile image" class="circle z-depth-2 responsive-img activator">
 {% endif %}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: it doesn't work, ok but what doesn't work, does it throw any errors or unexpected behavior? include a dump of *path*, detail a little bit more

Comment: what is the version of symfony?

Comment: try app.request.server.get('HTTP_HOST'))

Comment: symfony 3 is my version the dump of {{dump(path)}}   is  "http://mysite.it"  but wrong is the / at the end ..thank for help

Comment: I think, will be better to make twig extension for this job

Answer (score 1):

As the method name indicates `getSchemeAndHttpHost()` returns the current scheme (e.g. HTTP or HTTPS and the hostname). It does not contain the current request path. You need to access `app.request.pathInfo` for that information.

Maybe just getting the current route name is also sufficient for you. You can get it by calling `app.request.attributes.get('_route')`.